# Possible to index into contents of array subject to transpose function?

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90

In fortran, is it possible to index into elements of an array subject to an intrinsic? I am referring in particular to the `transpose` function. In the following code, I am generating and initializing an array named A and trying to index into a value inside the transposed array

```
program test 
    integer, dimension(5,3) :: A
    integer :: i,j

    A = reshape((/1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15/), shape(A))

    print *, transpose(A)(1,1)
end program test
```

however I am getting a syntax error as follows:

> **D:\TEMP\FortranTest>gfortran -o Test Transposecommand.f90 Transposecommand.f90:11:22:
>
> print *, transpose(A)(1,1)
>                         1 Error: Syntax error in PRINT statement at (1)**

It there a way to accomplish this without having to declare a separate variable then assign the transposed array to it? I would like to avoid declaring new variables if possible...

Comment: That's one of those "Why would you do that?" questions.  Why do you want `print *, transpose(A)(n,m)` when you can do `print *, A(m,n)`?

Answer (score 1):

No, Fortran doesn't support that kind of indexing into function results.  You'll have to devise an elegant solution of your own (*aka* a kludge).  My own would take account of

```
transpose(a)(i,j) == a(j,i)
```